# Writing matrix in Python, reading in Torch, what goes wrong

Tags: python, hdf5, torch

I have constructed a matrix in Python, a numpy array with data.shape is (249, 230). Here everything seems to be fine.

I write it to a hdf5 file with some simple code:

```
f = h5py.File("instructions.hdf5", "w")
f.create_dataset('/instructions', data=data)
f.close()
```

Now I want this data as as input for my neural network in Torch. (249 input samples of length 230). 
Therefore I try to read this hdf5 file into torch with

```
local datafile = hdf5.open('instructions.hdf5', 'r')
local input = datafile:read('/instructions'):all()
```

However when I do print(#input) I get an unexpected result, also with completely different numbers:

```
 1
 32
 32
[torch.LongStorage of size 3]
```

Does someone has an idea what goes wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to use [lutorpy](https://github.com/imodpasteur/lutorpy) to convert the numpy matrix to torch tensor. Lutorpy has a lua engine in python and be able to share numpy memory with torch, here is an example:

```
import numpy
import Image

## boot strap lutorpy
import lutorpy as lua
require('torch')

getImage = numpy.asarray(Image.open("image.jpg"))
a = torch.fromNumpyArray(getImage)

# now you can use your image as torch Tensor
# for example: use SpatialConvolution from nn to process the image
require("nn")
n = nn.SpatialConvolution(1,16,12,12)
res = n.forward(n, a)
print(res._size())

# convert back to numpy array
output = res.asNumpyArray()
```